# App cache manifest is getting cached by Firefox. How set header that allows caching and updating?

Tags: php, html, firefox, html5-appcache, offline-caching

When I server my manifest to Firefox it caches it. What header can I send with the manifest file (which is a PHP page) so it's not cached forever?

```
/* Firefox still caches the manifest with these headers */
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

This one also is ignored by Firefox:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
```

Comment: You must update the manifest file itself. app-cached files don't even make a network request unless if the manifest file is updated. You are confusing app-cache with networking caching which are 2 completely different systems :)

Comment: @NormanBreau You misunderstand. I made a change to the manifest file but still Firefox didn't update anything because it was caching the manifest file itself and not seeing the change. This appears to be a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683794